# PostgreSQL: Trigger Procedures

Tags: postgresql, triggers, procedure

I have these two tables in my postgresql database:

```
CREATE TABLE credit
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_emp integer,
  amount double precision,
  refund double precision,
  rest double precision,
  stat integer,
  CONSTRAINT credit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and this:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_with_credit
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_emp integer,
  stat integer,
  CONSTRAINT emp_with_credit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to create a procedure trigger `ON UPDATE` that does this work:
When I update a row the `credit` table I have to check if the rest = 0 then : set the `stat` column of the credit table = 0 and get the id_emp of the updated row and set the stat column of emp_with_credit table = 0 when credit.id_emp = emp_with_credit.id_emp
**EDIT:**
What I did so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION credit_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS $credit_stamp$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.rest = 0 THEN
        NEW.stat = 0;
    END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER credit_stamp BEFORE UPDATE ON credit
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE credit_stamp();
```

This works so good but still the second part where I have to set the `stat` column of `emp_with_credit` table = 0 when `credit.id_emp = emp_with_credit.id_emp`.

Comment: What did you try so far? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Looks like you need an UPDATE for table emp_with_credit in your function.

Comment: Never use floating point types (float, real, double precision) for money. Use numeric() instead.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' can you explain the difference ?

Comment: Floating point numbers are useful approximations. Money needs to be exact, not an approximation. This query returns *false*: `select 100.91::real = 100.91::numeric;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have UPDATE statement in your trigger.

```
CREATE FUNCTION credit_stamp()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.rest = 0
  THEN
    UPDATE emp_with_credit SET stat = 0 WHERE emp_with_credit.id_emp = NEW.id_emp
    NEW.stat = 0;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```